# Cómo guardar una imagen en mi carpeta img dentro de mi aplicación web con java?

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo en GuardarImagenes.java:

```
File file = new File(getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/img", "IMG_29.JPG");
Files.copy(e2, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Donde **e2** es un InputStream válido

Mis carpetas están así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo hago para que mi imagen que estoy moviendo (e2) se mueva satisfactoriamente a la carpeta **img** de mi proyecto?

Ahora mismo el error que me marca es este en la línea del Files.copy
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu error indica que no ubica el archivo IMG_29.JPG, en tu código te refieres a otro (IMG_25), ¿Valida si existe IMG_29.JPG y si tiene que ver con **e2**?

Comment: Perdón, es que le error lo saqué de una nueva ejecución. Pero ya lo edité. El problema está en que no encuentra la ruta y no sé cómo referenciarla a la carpeta imágenes.Cuál es la ruta para llegar a mi carpeta img desde java?

Comment: Si pulsas el botón derecho del ratón sobre el nombre del proyecto (en tu caso es multiSubida) y en el menú emergente que sale vas abajo del todo y pulsas en Properties, podrás ver bastante información de las rutas. Web Pages Folder es web y WEB-INF Folder es web/WEB-INF. En tu caso debes ir a multiSubida\web\img y así te encontrará el archivo sin problema. Recuerda que Web Pages es web solamente. Espero haberte aclarado las dudas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que puedo ver estas haciendo referencia a \multiSubida\img... esa ruta no es correcta debe ser \multiSubida\web\img.

Además, tengo entendido que para guardar imágenes en una carpeta con java necesitas la ruta absoluta y no la relativa. Por ejemplo "C:\Users\Usuario\multiSubida\web\img". Te recomiendo que en el explorador de archivos consultes la ruta absoluta de la carpeta "img".